# Having trouble centering elements on website

Tags: html, css

I was working on a personal website for someone, and I came across an issue centering his portfolio section on his page. The concerned page can be viewed at http://websitetesting.pro/portfolio.html, my website for testing purposes. The portfolio images are under the "figure" tag, but the problem should be under the class "rowone", as that's the parent element to the figure images. Here's the code for row one.

```
.rowone {
    height:240px;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    line-height: 240px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

If not in there, the error should be somewhere in either the "main" css, or the "portfolio" css which refers directly to the portfolio page.

Comment: What's inside `hover01 column`?

Comment: And please reformat your code, so that it can be viewed more cleanly

Comment: Reformat it? Sorry, like I said, this is my first time using stackoverflow.

Comment: Not the code in your question, but the code in the website itself. Just a friendly advice anyway

Comment: Ah, thank you. In which part are you referring too specifically? I only did part of it.

Answer (score 0):

The .column class is a block element which it fills the whole page by width. When set to inline block it retains a certain width and it can be moved around.

```
.column {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

or

```
hover01 {
 display: inline-block;
    }
```

options 2 is better. SO you wouldn't target a general class

Comment: This would be better if you can add some explanation as to why you arrived at this answer

Comment: Tried both of these, neither of them had any effect

Comment: Really? I tried it on your site using developer tool. "portfolio.css" line 78. and it worked

Comment: I was still unsuccessful, but I could be doing something wrong. Could you post the entire edited CSS, and I'll just switch the code and see if it works? Thanks

Comment: it looks like the layout as changed. if you revert it to the previous one try this  ".column.hover01 { display:inline-block !important}" that's to test.

Comment: Unfortunately this again was unsuccessful. I didn't change anything, here's the current .css setup. https://pastebin.com/HnXK1iF5

Comment: I see it's working to an extent. But the way your html is setup it would look nice responsively. because there are three imgs in a row. and when resizing it will become two imgs over one. When making changes don't forget to clear your cache "Ctrl + f5"

Answer (score 0):

```
.rowone {
    height: 240px;
    line-height: 240px;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, this did work. I've got under 15 reputations so it said my upvote doesn't show publicly, but it would still count.

Comment: I tried, I'm not able to because I don't have enough reps - just started stackoverflow today